# Chutzpah.json reference path not working - File too long message

Tags: jasmine, chutzpah

I am unable to run the testcases with Chutzpah.json as it throws me a file too long error message for some reason in the console output

I have all my unit testcases in UnitTesting Project which is in root folder which also contains WebPortal whereall my references exist

My Project structure is like

- WebPortal Project
- UnitTesting Project

My chutzpah.json is also in UnitTesting project (Am I referencing it correctly?)

```
       {
      "Framework": "jasmine",
      "RootReferencePathMode": "SettingsFileDirectory",
      "Tests": [
            { "Include": "*/*.js","Exclude": "*/*.d.ts" }
        ],
      "References": [
        { "Path": "../webportal/assets/scripts/angular/angular.min.js", "IsTestFrameworkFile": true },
        { "Path": "../webportal/assets/scripts/angular/angular-mocks.js", "IsTestFrameworkFile": true },
        { "Path": "../webportal/*/*.js", "Includes": [ "*.js" ], "Excludes": ["*.d.ts"] }

      ]

}
```

This is the error message I am getting always

---- Discover test started ------
Error: System.IO.PathTooLongException: The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters.
   at System.IO.PathHelper.GetFullPathName()

Comment: Do you have paths names over 260 characters?

Comment: My full absolute path name is less than 150 characters (I am still wondering what's causing this issue)

Comment: Do you have node_modules? You may want to make your tests declaration more specific so it doesn't scan all folders.

Comment: you mean inside each folder of testcases? may be that's the right way to go about it (this was a general chutzpah.json across a namespace)

Comment: I mean the way your Tests declaration is, it may be picking up ALL files in node_modules , which is bad